# Need to migrate from Java socket to Xmpp communication of my chat application

Tags: java, sockets, xmpp

Need to migrate from Java socket to Xmpp communication of my desktop chat application.
I got a api called SMACK for that but for that I have to use Openfire server i.e I can only code in my client. But I have my own socket server which I am using for my current chat application. Is there a way to use that server and write XMPP specific code in server?? basically reuse the socket server..?
I have written the code using SMACK which calls the server but how to make the server listen to that?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make your server understand and respond to the XMPP protocol.  In other words, you would have to write an XMPP server, which makes no sense when you can simply use one of many existing ones.  Using smack doesn't require you to use Openfire, but it is one of many options available.